# Transfer of funds from etherli to poloniex

Tags: ether, poloniex

I can not make the ethereum transfer from the etherli wallet to my poloniex wallet. The message is:

"Please fund your user account with sufficient ether (~0.01 ETH / tx) for gas (transaction fees)"

Can someone please help me?

Comment: What service provider is the wallet using? My guess is that you use local node which is not synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

How much Ether are you holding? The transaction price at most exchanges is 0.01ETH, some are lower. Check if you have sufficient balance to pay for a wallet transfer.

Comment: Yes, I have 24 ETH, I just want to transfer 1 ETH